# What options are out there to extract text from a group of PDFs where each PDF is formatted differently but contains the general same content

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text

Think insurance/medical forms that come from different companies.  There is no standard on formatting.  I am trying to extract the text based on each section of a given form.  A form might have a section of texted divided by whitespace, border, lines etc.  I need to keep the text in context of that section.

Textract from Amazon is something I am waiting for, but was wondering if there was some other alternatives.

Comment: Are you able to link a few PDF pages with personal data redacted?